# Why does input tags have more space between them than select tags while using twitter bootstrap form classes?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap form classes to create a form. I have used form-horizontal, form-group, col-* and form-control classes as shown in the code below. The problem is that when I have a block of select tags, and a block of input tags, the space between input tags is larger than that in the select tags. This way the form appearance is not uniform.
I have tried overriding this class;

```
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

to
    form-group {
      margin-bottom: 10px;//less margin-bottom
    }

But this reduces the space for both select and input tags. I can use a custom css class to reduce the space between the inputs, but I want to understand why Bootstrap is behaving this way.
Here is my code;

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">

    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label class="label control-label " for="DropDownListAccountFromDirectDebit">
                                    Account From</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-5">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListAccountFromDirectDebit" runat="server" CssClass=" form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True">
          <asp:ListItem Text="08409876556" Value="08409876556"> </asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="08467659594" Value="08467659594"> </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label class="label control-label " for="LabelCurrencyFromDirectD">
                                    Currency:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelCurrencyFromDirectD" runat="server" Text="USD"></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label class="label control-label " for="DropDownListAccountTODirectD">
                                    Account to pay</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-5">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListAccountTODirectD" runat="server" CssClass=" form-control" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="True">
          <asp:ListItem Text="LHO-002-067484000-02" Value="08409876556"> </asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="LHO-002-067484000-02" Value="08467659594"> </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label class="label control-label " for="CurrencyToDirectD">
                                    Currency:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
        <asp:Label ID="CurrencyToDirectD" runat="server" Text="USD"></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label class="label control-label " for="TxtAmountDirectD">
                                    Amount</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-5">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAmountDirectD" runat="server" CssClass="form-control " AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtAmountDirectD" ErrorMessage="Please Amount" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="DirectD" Width="8px">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
        <label class="label control-label " for="CurrencyDirectD">
                                    Currency:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-3">
        <asp:Label ID="CurrencyDirectD" runat="server" Text="USD"></asp:Label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">

    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
        <label class="label control-label " for="TxtStartDateDirectD">
                                    Start Date</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtStartDateDirectD" runat="server" CssClass="form-control " AutoPostBack="false" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtStartDateDirectD" ErrorMessage="Please Amount" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="DirectD" Width="8px">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm ">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
        <label class="label control-label " for="TxtEndDateDirectD">
                                    End Date</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEndDateDirectD" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-fixer" AutoPostBack="false" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtEndDateDirectD" ErrorMessage="Please Amount" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="DirectD" Width="8px">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
        <label class="label control-label " for="TxtChargeDateDirectD">
                                    Charge Date</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtChargeDateDirectD" runat="server" CssClass="form-control " AutoPostBack="false" type="date"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtChargeDateDirectD" ErrorMessage="Please Amount" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="DirectD" Width="8px">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Output for select tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIIfd.png)

[Output for input tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn0mG.png)

Comment: Show rendered HTML (not asp tags).

Comment: Can you post the rendered (not server-side) HTML instead. It will be easier to identify the issue.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser, select the elements in question and look at the box model to see where the additional margins/padding is coming from.

Comment: Using Chrome developer tools with a fresh mind this morning, I have managed to see where the additional margin is coming from. Thanks for the hint.